# sklearn difference between average_precision_score vs precision_score

Tags: scikit-learn, precision-recall

In the documentation it describes average_precision_score as area under the precision recall curve. I am having trouble understanding what does the area signify?

How is this metric different from just raw precision score.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The precision-recall curve plots precision and recall for different probability thresholds `p`. For `p=0`, everything is classified as 1 so recall will be 100% and precision will be the proportion of 1's in your test dataset. For `p=1`, nothing is classified as 1, so recall will be 0% and precision will be 0. For `p=0.5`, that's what `precision_score` tells you, however, you probably won't want to use this threshold in you're final model, you'll choose a different threshold depending on the number of false positives you're willing to tolerate. So the average precision score gives you the average precision of all the different threshold choices.